# My pod status showing OOM-killed, but doesn't restarted container. Why?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod

I am running POD with three containers, one app POD and two sidecar containers. Here app container memory limit is exceeded and doesn't restart. Inside the app pod, a Java app is running. Here is the describe POD command status.

```
Host Port:      0/TCP
State:          Waiting
  Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
Last State:     Terminated
  Reason:       OOMKilled
  Exit Code:    137
  Started:      Wed, 29 Sep 2021 09:41:50 +0000
  Finished:     Wed, 29 Sep 2021 09:42:47 +0000
Ready:          False
Restart Count:  14
Limits:
  memory:  300Mi
Requests:
  memory:  300Mi
```

Answer (score 1):

With `Restart Count: 14` it seems that the pod did restart. However the Restart does an exponential backoff. You can get insight into when the next restart will happen by looking at the `Events` and the `CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 20s restarting failed` part will tell you when it will be tried next.